# Careers Tweet Link already over limit for long links

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, twitter

When sharing a Careers job posting via Twitter, we are already over the tweet character limit.

Can you not shorten the url?

[image]

Comment: Twitter will automagically shorten the URL to a t.co link; the problem is *the length of the rest of the tweet*, which you can freely edit.